# At the TortoiseSVN Log Messages screen, is it possible to display a nickname for the author?

Tags: tortoisesvn

In my company our user names are non-descriptive (eg. g12345), so in order for the author to be quickly recognized, we start each commit message by including our name.
I do not think the feature exists, but if it were possible to display an alternate name for the author manually typing it would become unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SVN or TortoiseSVN have this capability if you mean your SVN user names.

If you are using logins as user names then you might configure SVN to use different user names as described in this question: [In Subversion can I be a user other than my login name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/405690/422353)