# How to remove saved password in Cygwin

Tags: git, svn, cygwin, repository

Sorry for a question that seems stupid, but neither I have any clue how to solve my problem. Because I looked onto the internet and got something

```
svn relocate svn+ssh://<new-user>@repository.server.com/var/lib/svne2/edumate2/trunk/
```

But it didn't work for me, as my SVN repository is on http (Example: http://svn.abc.com/folder-name)

I had once logged in to an SVN repository a long time ago. And whenever I commit the files it automatically gets committed because it would have saved in the cygwin somewhere.

But Now I want to login to the same repository as a different user, so that I can commit as another user, but unable to do so. (At first time it asked me to enter the password but now it doesn't. Now it is not asking for the password and being committing automatically).

Does anyone have idea How can I login as another user in cygwin?

Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with Git?

Comment: Cygwin is a GIT interface and logout procedure would be same in GIT as well. Because cygwin works with both GIT and SVN

Answer (score 0):

There were some similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671662/svn-change-username) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405690/in-subversion-can-i-be-a-user-other-than-my-login-name). I think that the easiest way is to use `--username` option with any svn command. E.g:

```
svn info http://svn.abc.com/folder --username your_username
```

New username will be saved after this command, and it will be used by default.